# Regular Expression - Linux - Between, But Not Including

Tags: regex, linux

I'm on Linux ( CentOS ) and I'm trying to capture from something that looks like

```
 This, formatting | is, 123gh234ee2, {absolutely}, [ positively | obnoxious | in ], {every}, [ {single} | {way} ],, Thanks | For your | Help!
```

What I want is to replace all pipes |, but only those within [ ].  So...

```
 This, formatting | is, 123gh234ee2, {absolutely}, [ positively ; obnoxious ; in ], {every}, [ {single} ; {way} ],, Thanks | For your | Help!
```

I've tried several expressions, but the one I think should work doesn't. Can anyone explain why?

```
sed -i 's/(?<=\[)(\|)(?=\])/;/g' 'myFile.txt'
```

My idea was do a look ahead for the [ with

```
(?<=\[)
```

Do a look behind with

```
(?=\])
```

And capture the pipes with

```
(\|)
```

However nothing in my file changes and I really can't seem to place my finger on what's wrong.

Thanks!

To clarify, I've also tried the perl method of

```
cat '/myFile.txt' | perl -ne 's/(?<=\[)(\|)(?=\])/xxxxx/g; print;'
```

And still do not get a changed result.

Answer (score 0):

Your lookbehind and lookahead regexes are trying to match single characters. They will probably work, if your input text contains exactly `[|]`.

In theory, you want your lookbehind to be something like `(?<=\[.*)` but the reality is that most engines don't handle arbitrary-length lookback.

You could use a sed `{command ; block }` to implement looping, appending various segments of the line to the internal buffer one at a time, then emitting the entire line once matching stopped.

A better idea, IMO, would be to switch to a language that would let you use the brackets to divide the text.

You could use awk, perl, or python, for example, to grab the text between `[]` and then process it separately. These would not be regular expressions, but small scripts.

Finally, another option might be to first replace your open brackets with a special tag, and your close brackets add a newline:

```
sed -e 's/\[/\n@[/g' -e 's/]/]\n/g'
```

This would put your bracketed text on their own lines, so you could follow that by doing a pattern-addressed linewide replace:

```
sed -e '/^@\[/s/\|/;/g' # On lines starting with @[ replace | with ;
```

Now you have to glue the lines back together, which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999934/sed-joining-lines-depending-on-the-second-one)