# scan and merge two lines in huge file (>5 Gb)

Tags: linux, unix, sed, merge

I have a huge file (>5 Gb), with a bunch of bugged lines. To fix it I need to:

1. Find the 'split' lines
2. Merge the 'split' lines of code together into the intended 'single' line of code
3. Save the corrected file

Original file: **(Notice the 'split' code in lines #113 and #114)**

```
...
#109=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.705232012855E0,-7.756877070089E-1,2.48166921056E0));
#110=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.705861274751E0,-7.7602308423645E-1,2.480686063358E0));
#111=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.705767565089E0,-7.764706427305E-1,2.472310353831E0));
#112=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.70570123242E0,-7.767839147852E-1,2.478226532593E0));
#113=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.7015612304515E0,-7.96452125292859E-1,
2.416457902634E0));
#114=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.701554931826E0,-7.9649012320387E-1,
2.4163429213930E0));
#115=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.705923512855E0,-7.756877070089E-1,2.481645657056E0));
#116=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.7058612374751E0,-7.7600123423645E-1,2.48068604563358E0));
...
```

Expected result:

```
...    
#109=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.705232012855E0,-7.756877070089E-1,2.48166921056E0));
#110=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.705861274751E0,-7.7602308423645E-1,2.480686063358E0));
#111=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.705767565089E0,-7.764706427305E-1,2.472310353831E0));
#112=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.70570123242E0,-7.767839147852E-1,2.478226532593E0));
#113=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.7015612304515E0,-7.96452125292859E-1,2.416457902634E0));
#114=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.701554931826E0,-7.9649012320387E-1,2.4163429213930E0));
#115=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.705923512855E0,-7.756877070089E-1,2.481645657056E0));
#116=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(1.7058612374751E0,-7.7600123423645E-1,2.48068604563358E0));
...
```

I think it is possible by using some combination of cut/paste/sed commands in Unix, Linux, Terminal, but I don't know how to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sed: joining lines depending on the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999934/sed-joining-lines-depending-on-the-second-one)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed, you can use `N` to add next line to the pattern space, check if newline character is not followed by `#` and merge if so:

```
sed -E 'N;s/\n([^#])/\1/;P;D;' file
```

Comment: Thanks! I installed [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/#download) (hoping that is what you referred to) and run your suggestion in Terminal, it run through the file, but I couldn't see any changes when I open it afterwards, so maybe I am missing a command to save the changes? Otherwise I cannot confirm it is working :/ I'm not really familiar with these kind text transformations.

Comment: Default output of this command is standard output(your terminal). If you want to edit your file in place, add the `-i` option : `sed -E -i 'N;s/\n([^#])/\1/;P;D;' file`

Comment: Thanks again! I think I'm still getting something wrong somehow. In Terminal, I go to the folder where the file is located and run this exact code: `sed -E -i .bak 'N;s/\n([^#])/\1/;P;D;` filename.stp It seems to run and it creates a backup file, but still identical to the -supposedly- debugged file. Am I still doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your input file may contain Windows line endings (`CR+LF` or `\r\n`). If so, please try instead: `sed -E -i .bak 'N;s/\r?\n([^#])/\1/;P;D;' file`